# Rails migration change sequence or order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I wrote a few migrations for my Rails 3 app, but I would like to change the order of the migrations. How can I change the migration order or sequence? Is it as simple as renaming the migration file with what appears to be the timestamp?

I know this is an odd question, but basically, I made a mess of my migrations and removed some old migrations and now I need to drop a table before creating a new one. I also know I can include the drop statement in the create-the-new-table migration, but I'm curious to know how to reorder migrations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it runs the migrations which have not been run in the order of the prefix.  In earlier versions of rails, maybe `2.1` or `2.2`, they used to be numbered starting with `01`, but they switched to timestamps.

There is a table which keeps track of which migrations have run.  The intentions is, multiple developers my have added migrations, and checked them in version control later.  So, there may be a migration which has not run, but is numbered before the highest numbered migration which has run.

If you change the migration sequence, (and I have) it's better to first down version before all the migrations you are re-sequencing.  Use the `VERSION` option with `db:migrate`.  If the highest numbered migration that you want to keep (not run the down) is `20120318143249`, call it this way.

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20120318143249
```

I often run the down on a migration, and re-run it until I get the details of the migration to my satisfaction.  Sometimes I re-order them, when I want to work on one of them, and I want it to be the last.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the prefix on the filename is what determines the order of execution. However, keep in mind this will only change your current system if you wipe your DB/start over.

Comment: Not always true. Assuming later migrations are reversible,  you can `rake db:migrate VERSION=<specific timestamp>` as suggested by @Marlin-Pierce

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue because the migrations were not happening in the right order.
After reading Mitch's answered I decided to **rename the migrations** to sequence the dates the way I needed.
After this fix I ran `rails db:migrate` and it worked.
Not the most elegant solution but it worked so I thought I'd share it.