# PG::UndefinedTable ERROR ruby on rails heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have been getting my application ready for production, and I am struggling with raking my database. It is giving me this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "events" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "events" ADD "code" character varying
```

Here is my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.postgresql
```

Here is my events migration file:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :partycode
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** 
when I run `rake db:migrate:status` I get the following result: 
[image]
Finally, here is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'

    gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.11'

    gem 'will_paginate'

    gem 'responders'

    gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

    gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'

    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

    gem "heroku"

    gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

    gem 'jquery-rails'

    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'


    group :development, :test do
      # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
      gem 'sqlite3'
      gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'web-console'
      gem 'pg'
    end

    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
    ruby "2.2.4"
```

Lemme know if there is anything else you need to solve this issue that I am having. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your `rake db:migrate:status` you have one problem that is a migration `Add code to events` should be after `Create events` migration because you are making changes in `event` but the table for that is being created afterwards. So you should fix this, and for temporary fix what you can do is:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20161219214142
```

`20161219214142` is the version of you `Create Events` migration, so this will run the specific migration for you and create the `events` table then if you will run `rake db:migrate` then it will work fine.

Comment: So how would I go about changing the order of these two?

Comment: @Aaron This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456761/rails-migration-change-sequence-or-order for changing the migration sequence. Meanwhile you can try the temporary fix.

Comment: worked like a charm, I can now see my production applicaiton